# Should manually updating the cache always be the preferred option after mutations as long as I get proper data from server?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am writing a CRUD app with React Query and I created some custom hooks as described here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/custom-hooks

In the docs I see that there are basically two ways to update the cache after a mutation:

- Query invalidation (https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation)

```
onSuccess: () => {
  queryClient.invalidateQueries("posts");
}
```

- Updating the cache manually (https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/invalidations-from-mutations)

```
// Update post example

// I get the updated post data for onSuccess
onSuccess: (data) => {
  queryClient.setQueryData("posts", (oldData) => {
    const index = oldData.findIndex((post) => post.id === data.id);

    if (index > -1) {
      return [
        ...oldData.slice(0, index),
        data,
        ...oldData.slice(index + 1),
      ];
    }
  });
},
```

I understand that manual update has the advantage of not doing an extra call for fetching the 'posts', but I wonder if there is any advantage of invalidating cache over the manual update. For example:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
const { API_URL } = process.env;

const createPost = async (payload) => {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  if (API_URL) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL, options);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("No api url is set");
  }
};

export default function useCreatePost() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation((payload) => createPost(payload), {
    // DOES INVALIDATING HAVE ANY ADVANTAGE OVER MANUAL UPDATE IN THIS CASE?
    // onSuccess: () => {
    //   queryClient.invalidateQueries("posts");
    // },
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData("posts", (oldData) => {
        return [...oldData, data];
      });
    },
  });
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state it yourself, the only advantage is that you don't waste another network call **to update data we already have**.

Here we have a create and delete example.

```js
 import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query'
 
 const queryClient = useQueryClient()

 // createPost(post: PostT) {
 //   const { data } = await http.post<{ post: PostT >('/posts', { post });
 //   return data.post;
 // }

 const mutation = useMutation(createPost, {
   onSuccess: (post) => {
     queryClient.setQueryData<PostT[]>(['posts'], (oldData || []) => [ ...oldData, post])
   },
 })

 // deletePost(id: string) {
 //   await http.delete(`/posts/${id}`);
 // }

 const mutation = useMutation(deletePost, {
   onSuccess: (_, id) => {
     queryClient.setQueryData<PostT[]>(['posts'], (oldData || []) => oldData.filter((post) => id !== post.id)
   },
 })
```

Invalidating the query can also be an option is some cases. The query will be invalidated and the data will be marked as stale. This will trigger a refetching in the background. So you know for a fact that the data will be as fresh as possible.

This can be handy if you got:

- multiple queries to update with data from a mutation
- have a (difficult) nested data structure to update

```js
 import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query'
 
 const queryClient = useQueryClient()

 const mutation = useMutation(createPost, {
   onSuccess: () => {
     queryClient.invalidateQueries('posts')
     queryClient.invalidateQueries('meta')
     queryClient.invalidateQueries('headers')
   },
 })
```

But it really is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! Invalidating multiple queries and nested data examples makes sense.
Seems like I may continue using manual updates for a simple app like mine (except the createPost mutation to prevent any possible issues with unexisting new post id, as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949561/1823278)

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of using manual updates comes from the fact that you can do it before the request is sent to the server; so if you manually update after the request is successful, then there's not much of an advantage if the data that you get from the server doesn't need to be immediately present to the user & in those cases (which I have found to be the majority) you better off invalidating. when you use optimistic updates, you assume the request is successful before you send it to server & then if the request fails you just roll back your update. this way your action happens instantly which is a better UX than doing the action, showing a loading spinner or something & then showing the updated state. so I have found it more useful for giving instantaneous feedback to the user than saving an extra request to the server. in most cases (as in yours) you still need to invalidate the query after, because your manually added post doesn't have an id, so you should sync it with the list of posts from the server. so be very careful about that because if you reading from that id somewhere else in that page, it would be undefined & would throw an error. so at the end of the day your mutation is not a great candidate for optimistic update & you should be careful to handle all the problems that can come up with your posts value having a post with no id in it (as opposed to something like a follow action which is just changing a boolean value in your database & you can confidently mutate the cache & undo it if request was not successful). so if we assume that you can handle that problem your useMutation hook would be something like this:

```
return useMutation(
  (payload) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData("posts", (oldData) => {
      return [...oldData, payload];
    });
    return createPost(payload);
  },
  {
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("posts");
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I see that you relate manual cache update especially with optimistic updates and it makes sense. Even if I don't use manual update for optimistic updates, it still feels like a good option as I am avoiding an extra call (for a simple example like this) but for create mutation, that's completely a valid point. Manual update without having a new post id is not a good idea. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with this statement: "so if you manually update after the request is successful, then there's no advantage & you better off invalidating." if the mutation response already sends you correct data, why would you want to refetch that? What if that request takes a couple of seconds? Would you deliberately delay showing that data to your users?

Comment: hey @TkDodo, You're right, that was too strong of a statement & I'd edit that out for future references. there are definitely cases which would make sense to update the cache after it is successful, but my point was more about the general approach that I have found works best with react query in a large codebase, which is try to manually update as much as you can but don't worry about a few extra requests if it's gonna increase your confidence in being in sync with the server.