# setQueryData not updating the cache with React-Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a very basic app where I'm trying to fetch some data, and update the cache. For example purposes I tried to update the data to an empty array, but on the dev tools and the console logs I keep getting the old data

```js
function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('repoData', fetcher, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData('repoData', () => []);
    },
  });

  console.log('data', data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```

what would be the correct way to update the cache?

Comment:  The basic correction is use new QueryClient() ounce in app (App.js)

 use useQueryClient() in other part of app to use same instance to update object

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to update the cache of the same item you have just successfully fetched? React-Query will put the result of the `fetcher` into the data field returned from useQuery - you don’t need to do anything in onSuccess for that

Comment: Apparently is not updating the data. I have the same issue.  The only solution I found is to invalidate the current data. @TkDodo

Comment: show a codesandbox reproduction please

Answer (score 2):

That's is an example from official documentation.

```js
 const queryClient = useQueryClient()
 
 const mutation = useMutation(editTodo, {
   onSuccess: data => {
     queryClient.setQueryData(['todo', { id: 5 }], data)
   }
 })
 
 mutation.mutate({
   id: 5,
   name: 'Do the laundry',
 })
 
 // The query below will be updated with the response from the
 // successful mutation
 const { status, data, error } = useQuery(['todo', { id: 5 }], fetchTodoById)
```

https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses

Answer (score 0):

The data resolved from your `fetcher` function will populate the cache from `react-query` with your chosen `query key`.

This data is available when destructuring the `useQuery` hook or is available with the `onSuccess` callback.

It can be usefull to manually update the data as shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949327/1934484

```js
// fetcher function
function getProducts() {
  // http call
  const { data } = await http.get<{ products: ProductT[] }>(/products);

  return data.products;
}

// data returned will be an array of products
const { data } = useQuery('products', getProducts, {
  onSuccess: (data) => {
    // data returned will be an array of products
  },
});
```